# Javascript - Read properties with variables

Tags: javascript

I am just learning to play with javascript and I wanted to be able to access a object I have via a variable name.

My data object is

```
    var browser =  ['chrome', 'safari', 'firefox', 'ie'];

  var browser_tasks = {
        chrome : 'chrome',
        firefox : 'firefox',
        ie :'internet explorer',
        safari : 'safari'

    };
```

and I want to be able to access it like

```
for (var i=0; i<browser.length;i++){
console.log(browser_tasks.browser[i]);
}
```

Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: `browser_tasks[browser[i]]`

Answer (score 1):

Yep - you need bracket notation when accessing an objects properties via a variable:

```
console.log(browser_tasks[browser[i]]);
```

Comment: Because this question *really* needed to be answered for a 50th time?

Comment: worth noting: `if(browser_tasks.hasOwnProperty(browser[i]))` to verify property exists.